# Can salt-call grains.get display only the value of the key?

Tags: saltstack

`salt-call grains.get cluster`

`local:
    up102`

Is there a way for salt-call to display only the value (eg. `up102`) without the rest of the output, or must I resort to using `awk` or `jq` etc to extract it?

I don't see any command line options to do this, but maybe there's a built-in way that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I didn't find a native solution for that. I mostly pipe it with `jq` this way:

```
# salt-call --out=json grains.get saltversion|jq '.[]'
"2017.7.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
salt-call --out=newline_values_only grains.get cluster
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer since OP did not want to use jq